# Can we upload build free and later same upload as paid version

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

Can we upload new applications on the App Store as Free and later can the same build be uploaded as a paid version? Is this feasible, will there be any issues? Or do we need a fresh build to change from Free to Paid?

Expecting that build can be accessible for everyone on app store but as Beta programm

Answer (score 0):

Beta testing program builds can be only free.
Release app can be released to the App Store as free and later on you can change it to be a paid one.